# how to rename files you put into a tar archive using linux 'tar'

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to create a tar archive with a couple files, but rename those files in the archive. Right now I have something like this:

```
tar -czvf file1 /some/path/to/file2 file3 etc
```

But I'd like to do something like:

```
tar -czvf file1=file1 /some/path/to/file2=file2 file3=path/to/renamedFile3 etc=etc
```

Where, when extracted into directory testDir, you would see the files:

- testDir/file1
- testDir/file2
- testDir/path/to/renamedFile3
- testDir/etc

How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can modify filenames (among other things) with `--transform`. For example, to create a tape archive `/tmp/foo.tar`, putting files `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` into it while also renaming `profile` to `foo`, you can do the following:

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s|bar|foo|' -cf file.tar file1 file2 bar fubar /dir/*
```

Results of the above is that `bar` is added to `file.tar` as `foo`.

The `r` flag means transformations are applied to regular files only. For more information see [GNU tar documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html).

You can use `--transform` multiple times, for example:

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s|foo|bar|' --transform='flags=r;s|baz|woz|' -cf file.tar /some/dir/where/foo/is /some/dir/where/baz/is /other/stuff/* /dir/too
```

Comment: That definitely works for renaming one file. How about renaming multiple files?

Comment: Multiple transforms and/or very clever regexps in them.

Comment: Could you give an example of multiple transforms. Do you just write `--transform=...` multiple times?

Comment: You probably have figured this one out of yourself already, but edited the answer to give you an exact example as well. Read to the documentation too, so you'll get a better hang of how this works (especially how flags for transforms work).

Comment: What to do if the search expression is a variable, and it should be treated literally?

Comment: For SEO’s sake, this works also for extraction and it was useful to fix a `Cannot open: Protocol error` issue I had when uncompressing a tar.gz with filenames with double-escaped dots (`\\.`) : I was able to clean them with `tar --transform='s|\\||g' -xzf archive.tar.gz` (note that `-xzf` must be after the `-transform`).

Answer (score 7):

With `--transform`, there's no need to make a temporary testDir first. To prepend `testDir/` to everything in the archive, match the beginning anchor ^:

```
tar --transform "s|file3|path/to/renamedFile3|" \
    --transform "flags=r;s|^|testDir/|" \
    -czvf my_archive.tgz file1 /some/path/to/file2 file3 etc
```

The `r` flag is critical to keep the transform from breaking any symlink targets in the archive (which also match ^).

Answer (score 5):

We can refer to the man `tar`, the `-O` option is the best choice since files can be written to standard out.

```
-O      (x, t modes only) In extract (-x) mode, files will be written to
         standard out rather than being extracted to disk.  In list (-t)
         mode, the file listing will be written to stderr rather than the
         usual stdout.
```

here are the examples:

```
# 1. without -O
tar xzf 20170511162930.db.tar.gz
# result: 20170511162930.db

# 2. with -O
tar xzf 20170511162930.db.tar.gz -O > latest.db
# result: latest.db
```

Comment: This is only for extraction, though.

Answer (score 0):

After not liking any solution that I've found, I've just written [tarlogs.py](http://danmbox.github.io/tarlogs/), which lets you specify arbitrary names for tar entries. Each tar entry is constructed from one (or several) regular (or gzipped) inputs. You can also add directories, which will be recursed into as with regular `tar`. So in your case,

```
tarlogs.py -o file1 -i /some/path/to/file2 -o file2 -i file3 -o path/to/renamedFile3 -o /etc >output.tar
```

(`-o` with no `-i` inputs simply uses the output path as input, with no renaming)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been up for a while, but for anyone who's looking for another suitable solution:
I've created [a fork](https://github.com/leso-kn/tar) of the original GNU tar utility with additional support for file name mapping.

Usage example:

```sh
> touch myfile.txt
> tar cf file.tar ':myfile.txt:dir/inside/tar/newname.txt'
> tar tvf file.tar
  -rw-rw-r-- user/user      0  2022-02-12 14:27 dir/inside/tar/newname.txt
```

The feature is triggered by prefixing file names with a colon (`:`) as shown above. A second colon functions as a separator between the source file location and the desired file name inside the archive.

`:[source file]:[desired name inside the tar]`

This feature is compatible with the `-T` (input list from file) flag.

**How to compile it**

```sh
> git clone https://github.com/leso-kn/tar
> cd tar
> ./bootstrap
> ./configure
> make -j4
# Run it
> src/tar --version
```