# Linux - how to rename files within a .tgz file without extracting contents and applying tar again?

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I have a tar file called test.tgz , inside it are the following files:

```
tool.foo
atest.you
btest.you
ctest.you
t.you
```

I want to rename the files inside test.tgz to be:

```
0.foo
0.you
1.you
2.you
3.you
```

Without the use of extracting the files and repacking them. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to extract them sorry.Actually i just searched(like you should have) and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790843/how-to-rename-files-you-put-into-a-tar-archive-using-linux-tar. You will have to unzip it though.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you can't rename the files **in** the tar archive, you can rename them with a sed expression on the fly while they are being extracted. The option to tar is`--transform [sed-expression]`.

Answer (score 0):

You **do** need to extract the files before you rename them. When files are in a tgz, they are protected from change.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your tar file through tools like [tarcust](http://www.fifi.org/cgi-bin/man2html/usr/share/man/man1/tarcust.1.gz) or [tardy](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/tardy.1.html) to edit the names of their members. Those operate on raw tar data, so you'll need to pipe them through `gunzip`/`gzip` too. For example, something like:

```
< original.tar.gz gunzip | tarcust OPTIONS GO HERE | gzip > new.tar.gz
```