# What are the ways to transform directory structure in a tar using tar command

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I want to create a tar file of a list of files.
The list of files should be read from a separate file named input.txt.

This is the content of the input.txt -

- **/var/opt**/SM/logs/rq/log.txt
- **/var/opt**/DC/mq/mqlog.txt
- **/var/opt**/config.cg

The compressed file should have a directory structure -

- **/logs**/SM/logs/rq/log.txt
- **/logs**/DC/mq/mqlog.txt
- **/logs**/config.cg

**/var/opt/** if exists in input file path, it should be replaced with **/logs**.

This is the expected output when I extract the tar file in say **root** directory.

- **root/logs**/SM/logs/rq/log.txt
- **root/logs**/DC/mq/mqlog.txt
- **root/logs**/config.cg

Comment: For using an input file to specify the files to archive see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8033898/10622916 for file name transformation see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421766/330217

Comment: What mentioned at unix.stackexchange.com/q/421766/330217 is at the time of extraction. I need it at the time of compression.

Comment: Did you try it? I guess not.

Comment: You likely do not want to replace the absolute path "/var/opt" with the absolute path "/logs". Instead you want to replace the absolute path "/var/opt" with the relative path "logs".

Comment: When it extracts to some directory say dir, it should extract as /logs/SM/logs/rq/log.txt and not as /var/opt/SM/logs/rq/log.txt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to rename files you put into a tar archive using linux 'tar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790843/how-to-rename-files-you-put-into-a-tar-archive-using-linux-tar)

Comment: @pzankat Almost no Linux system has the directory "/logs". Why do you want the logs in your root directory?

Comment: This is going to be implementation-specific, since there is no standard for `tar`. Are you using GNU `tar` (which I assume from the `linux` tag)?

Comment: Yes, I am using GNU tar.

Comment: This worked for me - 
tar -czf myarchive.tar -T /var/opt/input.txt  --transform='s|^var/opt/|logs|'

Answer (score 4):

Use the transform option:

```
tar cf archive.tar --transform 's%^var/opt%logs%' /var/opt
```

Comment: The input needs to be read from the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033857/tar-archiving-that-takes-input-from-a-list-of-files

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me -
tar -czf myarchive.tar -T /var/opt/input.txt  --transform='s|^var/opt/|logs|'

Answer (score 0):

The script below demonstrates a solution based on these questions and answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8033898/10622916
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/421766/330217

The commands are tested with GNU `tar` only.

```sh
#! /bin/sh
set -x

# prepare environment
mkdir -p foo/bar
rm -f input.txt
rm -f output.tar

for i in 1 2 3
do
        echo $i > foo/bar/file$i
        echo foo/bar/file$i >> input.txt
done

# create archive with file name transformation
tar cvf output.tar --transform='s|^foo/bar|baz|' -T input.txt

# list archive contents
tar tvf output.tar
```

output

```
+ mkdir -p foo/bar
+ rm -f input.txt
+ rm -f output.tar
+ for i in 1 2 3
+ echo 1
+ echo foo/bar/file1
+ for i in 1 2 3
+ echo 2
+ echo foo/bar/file2
+ for i in 1 2 3
+ echo 3
+ echo foo/bar/file3
+ tar cvf output.tar '--transform=s|^foo/bar|baz|' -T input.txt
foo/bar/file1
foo/bar/file2
foo/bar/file3
+ tar tvf output.tar
-rw-r--r-- bmeissner/1049089 2 2021-07-05 16:11 baz/file1
-rw-r--r-- bmeissner/1049089 2 2021-07-05 16:11 baz/file2
-rw-r--r-- bmeissner/1049089 2 2021-07-05 16:11 baz/file3
```