# How can I rename files within a tar.gz file during extraction of the tar.gz file?

Tags: tar

Simplified problem: I have a tar.gz file: Example.tar.gz
When extracted, it produces 1 folder named 2014, and 3 files within that folder named as follows:

a1:00:test

a2:00:test

a3:00:test

Objective: When extraction is complete, I want the folder to still be named 2014, but have the files within the folder named as follows:

a1-00-test

a2-00-test

a3-00-test

These files are on an ext4 file system, but the extracted contents must be on a ntfs file system which is not possible due to the illegal file names (:).

These tar.gz files are very large (30 GB), and I have over 70 of them. It would not be possible to extract all the files on the ext4 file system and rename them due to limited storage.

```
tar -xzvf /media/joshua/output/Example.tar.gz -C /media/joshua/elements/
```

Above code works normally, but not when extracting to the ntfs file system (due to illegal file name).

```
tar --transform='s/:/-/'-xzvf /media/joshua/output/Example.tar.gz -C /media/joshua/elements/
```

Above code suggested by @Barmar changes the first : to a - but not the second :

I have tried suggestions here: [how to rename files you put into a tar archive using linux 'tar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790843/how-to-rename-files-you-put-into-a-tar-archive-using-linux-tar) but I am new to Linux and having some trouble understanding the syntax, and applying it to my situation. Any help or general suggestions is appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have with the answers from the question you already found?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you have with renaming them after extracting. Renaming doesn't use any additional storage.

Comment: If there's not enough space on a filesystem that supports the names perhaps, @Barmar. But yes, being explicit about the problem would be useful.

Comment: Your best guess would probably be to extract the members individually but tell `tar` to write them to stdout (no additional storage required) and to pipe them into the final location then.

Comment: @Barmar When I extract the files, they become too large, so they would need to be extracted in an iterative process and renamed. A script can do this, but the process would take too long (many weeks).

Comment: The problem is that on ntfs files with a `:` are not allowed.

Comment: Are you trying to rename them inside the archive? I don't think there's any way to do that. I thought you just wanted to rename them when they're extracted.

Comment: In general, it's not possible to update tar files in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--transform` option as described in the question you linked to:

```
tar --transform='s/:/-/g' -xzvf /media/joshua/output/Example.tar.gz -C /media/joshua/elements/
```

`s/:/-/` replaces `:` with `-` in the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Barmar. This worked for a dummy test, I just did. However, I received the same error after a few minutes of run time: joshua:~> tar --transform='s/:/-/' -xzvf /media/joshua/WRFOUT/EMAQ_WA_4-07/WRFv3.8/output/2014/EMAQ_WRF_2014.2014-01-05.tar.gz -C /media/joshua/Elements/EMAQ_WA_4-07/WRFv3.8/output/2014/

2014-01-05/wrfout_d01_2014-01-05_00:00:00

tar: 2014-01-05/wrfout_d01_2014-01-05_00-00\:00: Cannot open: Invalid argument

Comment: Add the `g` modifier to replace all the `:` instead of just the first one.